# Is Chi-Square Test correct here?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I have a data set that talks about each age group of people answering total questions. The columns tell how many levels they passed. Here is how it looks like:
[image]

To calculate significance between age groups, i did a chi square test.
I calculated Chi value and it is unusually large. Is it expected or should i use a different test?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics and mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Comment: Hi Pang, i understand. But a lot of programmers would have this kind of use case, due to which i hoped i would get an answer here. Not with an intention to move away to an off topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test whether the two variables 'age range' and 'levels' are independent then the *chi-square* test could be an option. However, note that in order to use that test in a feasible way the expected frequency for each category should be greater than or equal to five and it does not seem to be the case in your example.

An alternative to *chi-square* test is, in these cases, Fisher's exact test, but it is computationally very expensive (only realistic for 2x2 tables and, with Freeman Halton's extension, maybe for only slightly larger tables). A realistic alternative would be to group categories and reduce its number.